# Link back to variable anchor on previous page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a simple page. On this page, I have blocks. The blocks get their unique ids when clicked open (example: http://blog.com/#brands). The ids are variable:

```
<div class="block wide" id="<?php echo $postid ; ?>">
 <a href="/blog/category/">blog category</a>
</div>
```

Someone clicks the link in the block & goes to the blog. Now the visitor is on the blog category page. But the visitor wants to go back to the homepage:

```
<span class="return-back"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">back</a></span>
```

But now, it is back to the top of the homepage. I want the visitor to be back at the variable id anchor of the blog:

```
<div class="block wide" id="<?php echo $postid ; ?>">
```

How do we make this happen? I am not a PHP developer (just CSS/JS/HTML). I've used Wordpress for this project. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Simply append `#your_id` after `bloginfo('url')`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand? What would the <a> look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually impossible to solve without rebuilding everything. The next page doesn't know what $postid is.

Answer (score 0):

The format for linking to a div through url is:

```
mypage.com/blog#blog_id
```

where `blog_id` is the id of the div you'd like to link to.

So, assuming `$postid` is the id of the div you want to link back to, try this:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); echo '#' . $postid;?>">back</a>
```

Comment: This looked great, but it doesn't work unfortunately... Maybe it's because the URL of the homepage changes when the block is clicked open to reveal the link? Sorry! I will edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: No it's my mistake, hang on, editing now... @user2970137 try it now. Whatever it is that `bloginfo('url')` produces, you need to concatenate `'#'.$postid` onto the end.

Comment: @user2970137 Probably because `$postid` is not the right value. That was just an example. Make sure `$postid` exists and has the same value on both pages.